# Unable to login to GitHub Package Registry

Tags: node.js, npm, github-package-registry

I am trying to release npm package through GitHub Package Registry, I am following the documentation, When I try to login using the below command after entering the `username` and `password`(even though both are correct), I am getting below error always.

```
// Step 2: Authenticate
$ npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

Error log:

```
npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
Username: ***********
Password:
Email: (this IS public) *****************
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Registry returned 401 for PUT on https://npm.pkg.github.com/-/user/org.couchdb.user:kgangadhar: Error authenticating user: Bad credentials

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\karth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-31T05_35_05_829Z-debug.log
```

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do you have 2-factor authentication enabled on your GitHub account? If so, try creating a personal access token and using that instead of a password. Here are [instructions to create a token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line).

Update: [Github now requires personal access tokens for all accounts, regardless of if you have 2fa enabled](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/)

Comment: what's the scopes needed by the registration token? tks

Comment: Select `repo` for the scope.

Answer (score 25):

I ran into this same issue because I was attempting to use my Github password to login, when in fact **you need to use a [Github Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) as the password**.

```
Username: YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME  
Password: YOUR_GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN  
Email: YOUR_EMAIL
```

Answer (score 10):

In this article refences the same command you are executing and the previous answer is correct. Just leaving here this to reinforce it:

[Link to Github configuration page](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-packages)

There just `Ctrl + F` in search for `npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com`

Answer (score 4):

As per 2023 here is how to publish a package to private GitHub NPM packages registry with the single `npm publish` command.

**Publish a Package**

Configure 3 follwing things:

1. Your GitHub repository: [create](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens) and save somewhere the access token
2. `package.json` (only fields relevant to publishing given, must configure the rest according to your project requirements)

   ```json
   {
     // Any instance of @my-gh-account-name must be a lower case
     "name": "@my-gh-account-name/my-package",
     "version": "0.1.0",
     "publishConfig": {
       // Prefix the registry with your account name as per below
       "@my-gh-account-name:registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
     },
     "repository": {
         "type": "git",
         "url": "https://github.com/my-gh-account-name/my-package-repository.git"
     }
   }
   ```
3. `.npmrc`

   ```yaml
   //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN}
   ```

   Create the `.npmrc` file as follows and assign `GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN` environmemt variable the token value created in 1. from your OS terminal (`GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN=token` in Linux or `$env:GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN="token"` in Windows 10) or any other way.

Now build your package into say `dist/` folder and then publish it with `npm publish ./dist` (`npm publish --help` for more options).

To publish packages under your GitHub organization replace `my-gh-account-name` above with an organization name.

**Install the Package**

At the Node application where you want to install the package create `.npmrc` file with the following content:

```yaml
@my-gh-account-name:registry="https://npm.pkg.github.com"
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN}
```

Then set `GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN` variable as in publishing receipe above.

Now issue `npm i @my-gh-account-name/my-package` command at your terminal. The package is installed.